# Unable to add reference for Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview component in VS 2017 .NET Frameworks 4.7.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am hoping that someone will be able to shed some light on this issue.

I was able to upgrade successfully to .NET Frameworks 4.7.1 and install the  Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview package using NuGet Package Manager.  However, when I try to add a reference in my WinForms project (in VS 2017) to Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview.dll (browsing to the NuGet packages folder in Windows Explorer), selecting the dll, and then clicking Add, the dll reference simply just doesn't get added.  I tried exiting and restarting Visual Studio and repeating the above steps, and get the same results: The dll does not get added to the References list.

I also tried adding the dll by clicking on the ToolBox, selecting "Choose Items" then then the .NET Framework Components tab, then clicked Browse (again, to browse to the NuGet packages folder in Windows Explorer), selecting the dll, and then clicking Add.  This time, I got the message shown in the attached screenshot:
[image: error message]

What am I missing?  Any insights/suggestions would, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I created a new .NET 4.7.2 WinForms project in VS2017 and was able to successfully install the package to the project. I think we'll need a [minimal, reproducable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help. About the second error, I wouldn't expect a WPF package to contain controls that works in a WinForms project.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> About the error message you get:

Maybe you should choose the **WPF Component Tab** instead of **.net Framework Component Tap** to add the Item.

See:

[image]

But `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview` package provide UI controls for WPF project instead of Winform project.

So when you click **Ok** you may get this page:
[image]

The controls from this package is for `WPF designer` instead of `Winform designer`, though they were successfully added to the Toolbox, you may can't use them well as what expected.

To use the Wpf controls of `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.Webview`, I recommend you create a WPF project instead of Winform Porject.

[image]

Any feedback would be expected:)